# How to truncate a KTable

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, linktable

I have a kafka stream app that utilize a KTable. My app has ran a while so the KTable is already built up.

How do I truncate the KTable (assuming my app can handle rebuilding the table)?

Is stopping my app and also delete data from the changelog topic the correct way? It seems a little complicate I feel there should be a simpler way.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "truncate" -- a `KTable` is a collection/set of key-value-pairs. What do you try to achieve? Please add more details to your question.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Basically I want to delete all existing key-value-pairs in that collection. But don't reset the kafka topic offset. So when the ktable come back it won't regenerate all existing values. But for new values coming to the changelog topic I still want to use them.

Comment: I see. So you read the KTable directly from a topic (ie, `builder.table()`) or is it a result from an aggregation? Also, how do you decide, when you want to wipe out the data?

Comment: It is from an aggregation. But does it change how we do it (vs if it's a `builder.table()`). This is not a frequent operation. It's only for our dev and testing, or maybe if prod got screwed we want to clean it up one time. Thank you for your help.

Comment: An example is: we might feed some invalid value to the input before, hence the aggregation generated invalid data in ktable. I want to refresh the ktable with newer correct value, but cannot just simply send all the keys again because some key no longer exists in my input topic.

Comment: Yes, there is a difference between both cases. For `builder.table()` there is not changelog topic, but the source topic is used instead (it's an optimization to avoid data redundancy -- both topics would contain the exact same data). For your example, I don't understand why you need to wipe out the whole store though?

Comment: I just want to start with a clean state for testing my change. This is at dev time. Or maybe there's a better way to do it other than wipe out the store?

Comment: For development, you can use the reset tool as describe in the docs: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/app-reset-tool.html

Comment: Thank you @MatthiasJ.Sax. To my understand the reset tool will delete the ktable's changelog topic correct?

Comment: Yes, it will delete all changelog and repartition topics.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to re-create the `KTable` from scratch, you can use application reset tool. That could be one option for you.

Application reset tool will delete all the changelog and repartition topics created for an application ID and hence for new run, you will get the new `KTable` and state store.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Streams+Application+Reset+Tool

Comment: It's good to know there is such a tool available, I'll look into it, thank you!